# Displaying foreign data in Kendo UI grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Got a MVC4, Entity Framework database first project with Kendo UI.

My model that I'm displaying in the grid looks like following:

```
public partial class RuleEntry
{
    public RuleEntry()
    {
        this.RuleEntriesCases = new HashSet<RuleEntriesCas>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Family { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IP { get; set; }
    public string RuleKey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Family Family1 { get; set; }
    public virtual IP IP1 { get; set; }
    public virtual RuleStatus RuleStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RuleEntriesCas> RuleEntriesCases { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute Country could be "SE" and is a foreign key to a table "Country" which would contain the name, "Sweden". The Country model looks like this:

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.RuleEntries = new HashSet<RuleEntry>();
    }
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RuleEntry> RuleEntries { get; set; }


}
```

I want a grid with all the RuleEntry data but with the corresponding foreign key names, at the moment only the key shows.
My grid code is like following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Country);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Family);
    columns.Bound(p => p.IP);
    columns.Bound(p => p.RuleKey);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Title);

})
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
.Filterable()
.ColumnMenu())
```

How do I do it? In the model, controller or view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RuleEntry class, add ForeignKey attribute for Country1 as below:

```
[ForeignKey("Country")]
public virtual Country Country1 { get; set; }
```

In your grid, use `columns.Bound(p => p.Country1.Name);`